# How to Insert Json Data in Mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to insert JSON data in single column in Mysql with PHP

```
<input type="text" name="text1" />
<input type="text" name="text2" />
```

```
$jsondata = '[{"value1":{ "text":"text1", "text2":"text2"},"value1":{ "text":"text1", "text2":"text2"}}]';
```

```
INSERT INTO tablename (row) VALUES ($jsondata);
```

it's possible

or We can generate a JSON file then import please guide me

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### Check this code this might help you:

---

**1 Read the JSON file in PHP:**

`PHP supports the function file_get_contents() which will read the entire file and returns it as a string.`

```
//read the json file contents 
$jsondata = file_get_contents('yourjsonfilename.json');
```

---

**2 Convert JSON String into PHP Array:**

```
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

`The first parameter $jsondata contains the JSON file contents. The second parameter true will convert the string into PHP associative array.`

---

**3 Parse the PHP Array Values and store in Variables:**

```
//get the details
$id = $data['Id'];
$name = $data['personal']['name'];
$age = $data['personal']['age'];
$streetaddress = $data['personal']['address']['streetaddress'];
$city = $data['personal']['address']['city'];
$state = $data['personal']['address']['state'];
$postalcode = $data['personal']['address']['postalcode'];
```

---

**4 Insert JSON to MySQL Database with PHP Code Now we will insert the
extracted JSON object values into the MySQL table using below query.**

```
//insert into mysql table
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_students(studentId, name, age, streetaddress, city, state, postalcode)
    VALUES('$id', '$name', '$age', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$postalcode')";
if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

---

**Now we have successfully imported JSON data into MySQL database as below:**

```
{
    "Id": "ST001",
    "personal": {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "age": "29",
        "address": {
            "streetaddress": "5 14th Street",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "postalcode": "12548"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Another way is:

```
<?php 

$josndata = '{
"student":{ "name":"Harry", "country":"United State", "ContactNo":2545454 }
}';  

// Database connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');

// Insert data Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO student_table ( name, jsondata )
VALUES ('Harry', '$josndata')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Insert your JSON record successfully";
} 
?>
```

Comment: want to import just on column like tabel row student, student_value import student={name=name,age=1,class=2,etc value} not multiple filed

Comment: check another solution I have added in answer

Comment: it's not working $sql = "INSERT INTO student_table ( name )
VALUES ($josndata)";

Comment: query is $sql = "INSERT INTO student_table ( name, jsondata )
VALUES ('Harry', '$josndata')"

Comment: can we create JSON Data same page from Form then insert  $josndata = '{by form submit}';

Comment: why you want to do it like that? means any specific requirement?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can read the json data by below query in php.

   $testdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
2. Then you convert the JSON data to array.

   $arrdata = json_decode( $testdata, TRUE );

   $test1 = $arrdata['test1'];
   $test2 = $arrdata['test2'];
   $test3 = $arrdata['test3'];
3. Finally you can insert the data into MYSQL table as per your requirement.

   $sql = INSERT INTO tbl_test (test1 , test2 , test3) values ('$test1', '$test2', '$test3');
   $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

This is example. you can modify the data as you required.